# How to distinguish caught and seen Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

In my Pokémon I have seen one Pokémon more than caught. How can I see which Pokémon I have only seen and not caught?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Pokédex overview you see the real pictures, non-colored pictures and numbers. The numbers are not seen at all, the colored pictures are caught, and the non-colored Pokémon are only seen. For example, Exeggcute (#102) is only seen.

[image: Pokédex overview]

Comment: Whoops. Exeggutor is 103, switching name soon.

Comment: Where'd you get a Rhyon?

Comment: @13aal at the edge of a city

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using the Pokedex to check, "seen" means that you actually encountered them. So if you have a good memory, you might remember all the Pokemon that you encountered but failed to capture. Interestingly, Pokemon fought in gyms don't contribute to "seen" like in the main series games.