# Is there any way to recover a Pokemon lost in a Pokemon Go app crash?

Tags: pokemon-go

I finally found a Squirtle and caught it, but then the app froze and I lost it.

However, my Pokedex still shows a picture of a Squirtle, but I don't actually have it. This isn't the first time this has happened to me, is there anything I can do to recover the Pokemon that this happened to? Any way I can fix this? Just an annoying bug?

Comment: is the pokemon greyed out like in the image in this answer? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273492/154022

Comment: I know the "original" i suggest is considerably newer, but the newer question is much better quality, and has much more upvotes. Voting to close this as the duplicate to retain quality.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do. Pokemon Go is exploding in popularity and there's both server timeouts and app glitches (probably caused by the server timeouts!) and unfortunately we just need to bare with those until things become a bit more stable.

The reason you're still seeing the Pokemon that you don't have is most likely because you've "seen" it but haven't "caught" it. "Seen" Pokemon are shown greyed-out in your Pokedex. You can also confirm this by checking the count at the very top of your Pokedex.

So, the best you can do is try to look for the Squirtle again. Sorry!

Comment: Well that disappointing, but it's okay, thanks!

Comment: @KennedySalts No problem. Since you're new to StackExchange, I'll also let you know there is a check mark to the left of each answer on questions you've asked. If you wish to mark an answer as correct, you can click that to do so - more here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers